# Here the answer is 75. So, Why 25 is multiplying with 3 here in this Scala program?

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

I am newly learning Scala, here in this Scala program the answer is 75. Why? Why 25 is multiplying with 3? I cannot understand that portion "println(fun(a))"

```
object MainObject 
    {  
       def main(args: Array[String]) = 
       {  
         functionExample(25, bhaskar)  // Passing a function as parameter  
       }  
        def functionExample(a:Int, fun:Int=>AnyVal):Unit=
        {  
            println(fun(a))            // 75
        }  
        def bhaskar(b:Int):Int = 
        {  
            b*3  

        }  
    }
```

Comment: fun:Int=>AnyVal is an argument to the method functionExample. In main you call functionExample with the fun argument as bhaskar. So the line println(fun(a)) prints the results of fun(a). a is 25 and fun is bhaskar. bhaskar returns a*3.

Comment: ok thanks! but how bhaskar returns a*3? it returns b*3. Can't get sorry

Comment: bhaskar takes one argument, b, which is an int. When it is called in functionExample, a is passed as the argument. So b=a, then b*3 is returned.

Comment: Yes! Thanks! Got it! :)

Answer (score 2):

`println(fun(a))` prints the result of calling `fun(a)`. When you call `functionExample(25, bhaskar)` you pass in `25` as `a` and `bhaskar` as `fun`.  `bhaskar` takes an `Int` and returns that multiplied by `3`.

Therefore, the result of calling `bhaskar(25)` is `75`.  Since `fun` is `bhaskar` and `a` is `25`, `fun(a)` results in `75`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

But how bhaskar is taking an Int 25? Because 25 is the first argument and bhaskar is the second argument overhere. In the implementation part of bhaskar(b:Int) here b is a variable never used before

Comment: because, when you called the function you passed in 25 as a, and bhaskar as fun.  so then fun(a) is the same as bhaskar(25).  bhaskar that in the input value and multiplies it by 3 and returns that result.  b is the name of the parameter of bhaskar, it is local to the method.

Comment: Yes. Got it. Thanks!